# What is the user agent used by Helo App to crawl sites?

Tags: browser, web-crawler, user-agent

In my web server, I'm trying to detect when [helo App](https://studio.helo-app.com) crawler is hitting my site, then fetch a response on my server and return a generated page (with minimum meta info) instead of the normal JS page.

I'm trying with **ToutiaoSpider** userAgent for helo. But it is not working. Does anyone know which user agent is used by helo App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helo uses **ToutiaoSpider** only as their userAgent.